# how to get XML output through WCF based webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wcf

I have a WCF based webservice and inside the method I am executing a stored procedure and filling dataset then at the end returning the dataset back..like one column and multiple rows. But my requirement is different now as I am calling this webservice through some other product which expects the output based on XML like this. (its a sample XML format) but i want something in the same manner. so how do i generate the xml and return it..I would appreciate if someone can make corrections in the given code as I am not XML guy this is the first time I am going to deal with XML. I would like something

```
<xml>
   <Approvers>
      <Approver>
          <Approvername>John</Approvername>
      </Approver>
   </Approvers>
</xml>
```

Sample XML format which i want to follow.

[image]

```
public DataSet getRequisitionApprovers(string pEmail, string pLocationType)
        {
            //Read Datasource properties from Web.config file to access Oracle EBS Database 
            string SDataSource = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLDataSource"].ToString();
            string SUserID = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLUserID"].ToString();
            string SPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLPassword"].ToString();

            //Build connection string based on retrieved parameters from web.config file
            string connectionString = "Data Source=" + SDataSource + ";Persist Security Info=True;" + "User ID=" + SUserID + ";Password=" + SPassword;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // Name of procedure or function to be execu
                command.CommandText = "Get_RequisitionApprovers";

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("theEmail", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = pEmail;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LocationType", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = pLocationType;

                //Create New DataSET & DataTable
                DataSet dsApprovers = new DataSet();
                DataTable dtApprovers = new DataTable();

                //Create DataTable Columns and define the data type 
                dtApprovers.Columns.Add("Approver1", typeof(string));


                //Add DataTable to DataSource
                dsApprovers.Tables.Add(dtApprovers);

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //Create new Data Row
                    DataRow theRow = dsApprovers.Tables[0].NewRow();

                    theRow[0] = reader[0].ToString() ;   //Add -> Approver

                    dsApprovers.Tables[0].Rows.Add(theRow);
                }

                return dsApprovers;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12PGpwy8SUY). It's short but very much to the point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning Raw XML From a WCF Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232579/returning-raw-xml-from-a-wcf-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the video, you're pretty close to figuring this out.

Make sure you set the `DataTable.TableName` because if you don't, it won't serialize.

All that remains is [setting up the WCF Service](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12PGpwy8SUY) and defining a `WebMethod` returning an XML string from your `DataTable`.

After setting up your WebService, defining a WebMethod and returning the XML goes like this:

```
//StringWriter requires System.IO
using System.IO;

//This are hypothetical Class and WebMethod names, of course
public class RequisitionApprovers : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string ReturnRequisitionApproversAsXMLString(DataSet ds)
    {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        ds.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
        string xmlResult = writer.ToString();

        return xmlResult;
    }
}
```

All that's left now is to remove the "\r\n" and the whitespaces from the xml string where needed and you end up with a clean xml string to have your `WebMethod` return.

Comment: Wim I've followed your code but the output in the calling application encountring error reading my string..when I pint the output it is something like..
.&lt;Approvers&gt;  &lt;Approver&gt;    &lt;ApproverEmail&gt;Lawrence.P@abc.com&lt;/ApproverEmail&gt;  &lt;/Approver&gt;&lt;/Approvers&gt;

Comment: if you run the webservice in a browser, do you see the &gt and &lt entities as well? or is it only on the client side?

Comment: its like this.......in browser but the recieving end has encoding..
"<Approvers>  <Approver>    <ApproverEmail>Lawrence.Pa@abc.com</Approver" +
    "Email>  </Approver></Approvers>"

Comment: I would like to know how to generate a compatible file which is acceptable to my 3rd party application which is recieving the xml string

Comment: A webservice doesn't usually return files. An XML String should suffice, once you got in cleaned out. Can you clarify?

Comment: sorry my mistake..i mean how to generate a compatible string..i guess UTF8 is required here..what do you think?

Comment: if you're using unusual chars in your xml, then go with UTF-16. For standard English, UTF-8 should suffice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24020/discussion-between-user342944-and-wim-ombelets)

Comment: Wim I am accepting your answer as you guided me how to convert the xml into string..no need to convert into UTF8 as in my workflow product there was Regular Expression action and Ive used it and replace &lt; with < and &gt; with > ..problem solved :) thanks anyway